# How can I access head and tail of a linked list in a global function?

Tags: c++, singly-linked-list

On my exam I had a question where I had to implement a global function outside of my class to reverse the contents of a list that is passed in as a parameter. I had no idea what to do.
I know how to do it if I had to implement a reverse function that was part of the IntList class:

```
const int IntList::front() const
{
    return head->data;
}

int IntList::count() const
{
    int count = 0;
    for (IntNode *i = head; i != 0; i = i->next)
    {
        ++count;
    }

    return count;
}

void IntList::reverse(IntList &list)
{
    int counter = count();

    while (counter != 0)
    {
        list.push_front(front());
        pop_front();
        --counter;
    }
}
```

However, on the test I didn't have access to the count() function to figure out how many times I needed to call push_front() and pop_front() on the list. I was wondering if there was a way I could have accessed the private data members to loop through the list? Or am I thinking about this the completely wrong way?

What I was given:

```
struct IntNode 
{
    int data;
    IntNode *next;
    IntNode(int data) : data(data), next(0) {}
};

class IntList
{
    private:
        IntNode *head;
        IntNode *tail;
    public:
        IntList();
        IntList(const IntList &cpy);
        IntList & operator=(const IntList &rhs);
        ~IntList();
        bool empty() const;
        int front() const; //implement
        void push_front(int value); //implement
        void pop_front(); //implement
        void push_back(int value); //implement
        void pop_back(); //implement
};

void reverse(IntList &list); //implement as global function
```

Comment: Well, how does `count()` know that it should stop counting?

Comment: On an unrelated note, returning a constant value from a function have no meaning. It can be assigned to a non-constant variable by the caller anyway. Returning a *reference* to a constant value is something altogether different though.

Comment: Are you sure you were give this List structure? Without API to populate it?

Comment: Probably he had to build the API as part of the assignment. Anyway, answering that part of the quesiton: no; there is no way to access private members *(that is, unless a public method hands it out on purpose)*, and there should not be. The very reason they are made private is to separate the interface (what the object does) from the implementation (how it does it). Code outside the object should only concern itself and know about the interface, and marking members private is a tool to enforce that.

Comment: Oops! Sorry I made an edit to fix the post. I included the other functions and removed the const I added by accident to the front() function

Comment: That is not enough. You must also either provide a method that lets outside code know when the list is empty, or define a [sentinel value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value) (a special value that `front()` will return that means "there is not front, list is empty).

Comment: Added the empty() function.

Comment: Having the `emtpy` function, you know how often you need to call `pop_front`.

Comment: So would it be correct to create a loop that keeps calling push_front() on the value returned by front() into another list and pop fronting the original list until empty() returns true, and then having another loop to push back all of the values back into the original list again?

Comment: @aqw143 yes that sounds more or less OK to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following implementation solves your problem

```
void reverse(IntList &list)
{
    IntList previousList = list;   //Store the previous list.
    list = IntList();              //Initialise a new List.
    while(!previousList.empty())
    {
        int frontValue = previousList.front();
        list.push_front(frontValue);
        previousList.pop_front();
    }
}
```

You need not know how long the list is to reverse it.